# Azure DevOps - Deploy Build Published Artifacts to Feed

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

Am newbie to Azure DevOps. Am using node build.js command to build my project. Using PublishBuildArtifacts Task I am able to publish artifacts and able to view the artifacts in build pipeline published artifacts.

I would like to deploy the copy of the published artifacts to the feed(feedname - deliverables).

Please suggest the task to be performed.

Azure-pipeline.yml.

#Node.js and NPM for package

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: windows-2019

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '16.x'
  displayName: 'Node.js Install'

- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'install'
    workingDir: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\OnlineBooking'

- script: |
    workingDir: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    node build.js
  displayName: 'Build Project'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: 'D:\a\1\s\temp\OnlineBooking\build\wap\build'
    Contents: 'OnlineBooking.zip'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    CleanTargetFolder: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'OnlineBooking'

- task: UniversalPackages@0
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    feedsToUsePublish: 'internal'
    vstsFeedPublish: '60b130c2-758b-4b91-975e-95da6dafe48c/fe327ef2-792e-4358-895b-df858e27ac2d'
    vstsFeedPackagePublish: 'test'
    versionOption: 'custom'
    versionPublish: '1.1.0'
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, Have provided the details in below response. Can you reply

Comment: Can you share some screenshots about the package content? When you upload the artifacts to universal package, you can download it and check if it has the required files.

Comment: Hi Kevin, sorry for the delayed reply. Universal package is created. But only way to download the file via Azure CLI only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description, you need to publish the build artifacts to feed.

I suggest that you could use the task: [Universal packages task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/universal-packages?view=azure-devops)

Here is an example:

```
- task: UniversalPackages@0
  displayName: 'Universal publish'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    vstsFeedPublish: 'feedname'
    vstsFeedPackagePublish: test
    versionOption: custom
    versionPublish: 1.1.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion I have tested it out. Test universal package is created, but zip file is not available in the package. Its null.  Able to view only pipeline build artifacts. Have attached the updated yaml in the question section.